# Office Add-in: Saving Custom Document Properties with Office js in Windows

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, word-addins

#### Background:

I'm developing an add-in in *macOS* and I am able to read a custom document property:

```js
return await this.api.run(async (context) => {
    const properties = context.document.properties.customProperties;
    properties.load('key,type,value');
    await context.sync();

    const roomID = properties.items.find(item => item.key === 'Webex_Teams_roomID');
    return roomID ? roomID.value : null;
  });
```

and write one:

```js
  return await this.api.run(async (context) => {
    context.document.properties.customProperties.add('Webex_Teams_roomID', newRoomID);
    await context.sync();
  });
```

Where **this.api** is just **window.word** using `office JS API`. I used help from the following repo which is offered by Microsoft themselves, [office-js-snippets](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/blob/master/samples/word/07-custom-properties/read-write-custom-document-properties.yaml#L14).

#### Problem:

I'm not able to run my code in window's machine. After debugging the code, I learned that my code gets stuck at this point: `await context.sync();`.

#### Office Versions:

Office Versions in macOS: `16.14.1 (180613)`.

Office Version in Windows: `16.0.4639.1000 32-bit`

#### Update:

After some digging, I found that I don't have access to `context.document.properties.customProperties.items`. It will display `<permission denied>` error. Could this be it?

And I set the `Permissions` to `ReadWriteDocument`:
  `<Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>`
Nothing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out with this MSI build and the API that I'm using, there are some incompatibility issues that result into causing the problems that I had ealier. they suggest I move to 365.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that this has to do something with how async/await (not)works on IE11 and that you will have to add correct polyfill to handle this.

Comment: that's a very good point. Let me check it out. Please look at my updated post as well.

Comment: As It turned out, `Async/Await` works fine on IE 11. As I tested my code separately on IE 11. So I think the problem is reading document properties. For some reasons Office API is not allowing to read the `items` property from `context.document.properties.customProperties`.

Comment: If everything works after updating permissions great but I still think it is a bug because I would expect same behaviour on Mac and Windows versions of Office with the same set of permissions. If you have read permissions you should only read properties and get permissions denied on write. If you are certain that this is the case and you can spare 10 mins please go and open a ticket at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues you might help someone else facing the same issue.

Comment: Issue created [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/202)